# Cross-Origin Request Blocked error whenever we try to start our project when pulling from git

Tags: c#, asp.net, cors

We have the following scenario.

1. Developer A opens a asp.net zero demo project from web.sln
2. Afterwards he immediately pushes the code to git repository
3. Developer A runs web application and sees index or landing page
4. Developer B and C pull the code from git server and try to run it resulting in the following errorcode:

"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same-Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:5001/AbpUserConfiguration/GetAll?d=1681805995669. (Reason: CORS request failed). Status code: (null)."

What we have tried:

1. Deinstalling random shitty Antivirus Software
2. Adding .AllowAnyOrigin() to services.AddCors

None of these things work and the error seems to be only occuring after pulling the code. I tried to compare some files trying to notice any difference but there wasnt. I hope someone know what could be causing these problems.

Comment: Your website is not running on `localhost:5001` is it? And what exactly is serving `https://localhost:5001`? It must be something only A's machine has.

Comment: localhost:5001 is the api which serves the client running on port:4200 the data to display. The api can be started by every developer by running the web.host project. The client runs with npm start